# JavaScript Function working but first time only: Owl Carousal + bootstrap Tabs

Tags: bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

I am trying to implement OWL carousal with Bootstrap 4.

My problem is this function :

```
$(".casestudy-tab .threecol").owlCarousel({
        pagination: !1,
        navigation: !0,
        rewindNav: !1,
        responsive: !0,
        items: 4,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 4],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 2],
        itemsTablet: [768, 2],
        itemsMobile: [500, 1],
        afterAction: t
    });

$(".casestudy-tab .threecol li").click(function () {
    $(".casestudy-tab .threecol li").toggleClass("active");
});

function t() {
    $(this.owl.owlItems)
        .find("li").removeClass("active"),
        $(this.owl.owlItems[this.owl.currentItem])
            .find("li").addClass("active"),
        $(this.owl.owlItems[this.owl.currentItem])
            .find("li").find("a").click();
}
```

Find the codepen link here: https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/YRBvgo

when clicking on upper links, this code is working but only once. first time all three tabs are showing perfectly but second time it will not.
I am not getting where I am doing the mistake, Please help me out

Comment: On your last line of 't' you have `.find("li").find("a").click();`

`.click()` binds a handler. Did you mean click or `'.trigger('click')

Comment: actually I just want to click on the a, I dont know the difference between .click and .trigger('click'); I tried this also after your comment but the result is same,

Comment: `trigger(<eventname>)` is how you programatically trigger an event. `<element>.trigger('click')` is how you would click on an element programatically. `<element.click(<function>)` is how you bind an event to an element so that it is triggered when it is clicked.

Comment: ohk, but its not the solution for my problem... Please look into code once and help me out